# evaluated at compile time

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

**What the difference between two examples?**

example 1:
`int x = int.MaxValue + 1; // Compile-time error`

example 2;
`int x = int.MaxValue; x = x + 1; // no Compile-time error`

The Author of A Nutshell book said about the first example **that expressions evaluated at compile time are always overflow-checked.**

**I didn't understand the difference between the first and second examples. Isn't both evaluated at compile time, so should both produce the same error?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int.MaxValue` is a constant value, so the compiler can calculate `int.MaxValue + 1` and determine that it overflows the range of `int`.

The compiler is *not* sophisticated enough to know that `x` is `int.MaxValue`, calculate `x + 1` and determine that it overflows.

The compiler does not "evaluate" the second - it just turns the expressions into the equivalent IL code that is evaluated when the program runs (which would obviously overflow at runtime).

If the first example used a constant expression that did *not* overflow (e.g. `int.MaxValue - 1`), the compiler *could* replace the expression with the result of the constant expression in the IL.

That's all that's meant by "evaluated at compile-time"

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't both evaluated at compile time, so should both produce the same error?

No, compiler (as far as I know) evaluates only the constant expressions and the second isn't one.

So `x + 1` in the following:

```
int x = int.MaxValue; 
x = x + 1; // no Compile-time error
```

Is not a constant expression. I.e. if you will change it to:

```
const int x = int.MaxValue; 
int x1 = x + 1;
```

it will produce the compile-time error.

A bit of specification deep dive:

From [specification: 12.8.19 The checked and unchecked operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12819-the-checked-and-unchecked-operators):

> When one of the above operations produces a result that is too large to represent in the destination type, the context in which the operation is performed controls the resulting behavior:

> - In a checked context, if the operation is a constant expression ([§12.23](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1223-constant-expressions)), a compile-time error occurs. Otherwise, when the operation is performed at run-time, a `System.OverflowException` is thrown.

And in the [12.23 Constant expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1223-constant-expressions) part of spec:

> Only the following constructs are permitted in constant expressions:
>
> - Literals (including the `null` literal).
> - References to `const` members of class and struct types.
> - References to members of enumeration types.
> - References to local constants.
> - Parenthesized subexpressions, which are themselves constant expressions.
> - Cast expressions.
> - `checked` and `unchecked` expressions.
> - `nameof` expressions.
> - The predefined `+`, `–`, `!`, and `~` unary operators.
> - The predefined `+`, `–`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `<<`, `>>`, `&`, `|`, `^`, `&&`, `||`, `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=` binary operators.
> - The `?:` conditional operator.
> - `sizeof` expressions, provided the unmanaged-type is one of the types specified in §23.6.9 for which `sizeof` returns a constant value.
> - Default value expressions, provided the type is one of the types listed above.

Answer (score -3):

The key difference is that example 2 is two expressions. The first assigns the int x, the second increments it. Example 2 can be re-written as:

```cs
int x = int.MaxValue;
x = x + 1;
```

The point that the author is making is that the compiler doesn't check the second expression for integer overflow.

Comment: What do you mean by "rewritten" it is already in that form.

Comment: I was attempting to make it explicit that the second example is two expressions. I could have used "refactor" to be more precise.